# Is it possible to use window.postMessage() to stream data?

Tags: javascript, html

Specifically, I'm wondering if it's possible to send and receive Mic/Cam data between iframe and parent using Window.postMessage().

Comment: Yes, this is possible

Answer (score 0):

If the windows are in the same origin, you can exchange data directly between them by having one window call a function from the other window.

If not, in theory you could allocate a typed array for the data and send it to the other window via `postMessage`, listing it as a *transferrable object* so it doesn't have to be copied (instead, the sending code loses access to the underlying memory, which the receiving code get access to instead). See the `transfer` parameter on [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage).